# Bug with the rep-cap

Tags: bug, reputation, votes

Today I hit the repcap with 200 rep (in fact I got a few null upvotes after that, so that I 'should' have been on 230 rep). Then somebody undid their upvote on one of my answers<sup>1</sup>, putting me down to 190 rep. After that, every upvote I got still counted as null: apparently **my maximum rep today is 190**.

Surely this isn't how the system is meant to work? I know from experience that if someone loses rep after hitting the repcap by *being downvoted* or by *downvoting answers*, then the next upvote they get brings back the rep they lost. I can't see why it should work any differently when they lose rep by *having upvotes reversed*.

**Is this behaviour intentional or a bug?**

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>(I suspect this unupvote was *accidental*, since I hadn't made any major edits since posting the answer, except to explain some of the clues better after help from the OP. But that's neither here nor there.)</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236420/180276

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks for the link. What does "You will now have a 10 rep discrepancy between visible rep and audit rep." mean??

Comment: @randal'thor http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: @Kevin Wow, thanks! I'd never come across that link before.

Comment: It's one of the [unlinked pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/172958), you have to know it's there and type in the URL.